# Is a convex cone which is generated by a closed linear cone always closed?

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls, convex-cone

Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a **closed cone** which contains zero. (i.e. $\lambda C \subseteq C$ for every $\lambda \ge 0$).

> Let $P(C)$ be the convex cone generated by $C$, i.e. the set of all positive linear combinations of points in $C$. Is $P(C)$ closed?

In general, the cone generated by a closed (and even convex) set containing the origin may not be closed, as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/701791/104576).

Here I assume that the generating set is a (linear) cone. Does that change things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true, and a counterexample in $\mathbb R^3$ can be found.

Pick two closed convex cones $K_1,K_2$ whose sum $K_1+K_2$
is not closed, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712188/how-can-the-sum-of-two-closed-cones-be-not-closed).

Now simply define $C:=K_1\cup K_2$.
Then the set $C$ is closed, but the convex cone generated by $C$ is $K_1+K_2$, which is not closed.